# Green's generating function for random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

Tags: generating-functions, random-walk, greens-function

Let $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a simple symmetric random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^d$, in continuous time (holding times are $Exp(1)$ random variables). Moreover, suppose $X_t$ is **killed** after walking for a time $T_{\lambda}\sim Exp(\lambda)$.

For such a walk $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ starting from the origin, I am interested in the probability that $X_t$ hits site $y\in\mathbb{Z}^d$ **before being killed**, i.e.

$$
\mathbb{P}_0(\tau_y<T_{\lambda}),
$$

where $\tau_y=\inf\{t\geq0\,:\,X_t=y\}$ is the hitting time of site $y\in\mathbb{Z}^d$.

Such a quantity has already been considered in the literature, for example in "Random Walk: A Modern Introduction" by Lawler and Limic [RW], where it is called "**first visit generating function**", and denoted by

$$
F(x,y;\lambda)=\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_y<T_{\lambda}).
$$

The only difference is that in [RW] time is discrete, $\tau_y=\min\{n\geq1\,:\,X_n=y\}$  and $T_\lambda$ is a Geometric random variable such that $\mathbb{P}(T>j)=\lambda^j$. The name "generating function" is due to the fact that in discrete time, as shown in [RW],

$$
F(x,y;\lambda)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lambda^nf_n(x,y),
$$

where $f_n(x,y)=\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_y=n)$.

Going back to continuous time, after some standard computations one gets that

$$
\mathbb{P}_0(\tau_y<T_{\lambda})=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb{P}_0(X_n=y)(\lambda+1)^{-n}}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb{P}_0(X_n=0)(\lambda+1)^{-n}}
$$
where now the walk $(X_n)$ on the right had side is actually in **discrete time**. The function appearing at the numerator and denominator on the rhs has also been already considered in the literature, for example in [RW] is called "**Green's generating function**" and denoted by

$$
G(x,y;\xi)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb{P}_x(X_n=y)\xi^{n}.
$$

As shown in [RW], for positive $\xi\leq1$, $G(x,y;\xi)$ is the **expected number of visits of the random walk (in discrete time) to $y$, starting from $x$, before being killed** (killing time $T_\xi$ is such that $\mathbb{P}(T_{\xi}>j)=\xi^j$).

With this notation, one gets that

$$
\mathbb{P}_0(\tau_y<T_{\lambda})=\frac{G(0,y;(\lambda+1)^{-1}))}{G(0,0;(\lambda+1)^{-1})}.
$$

I am looking for ways to work out the dependence of the rhs above from $y$ and $\lambda$, and hence for estimates on the Green's generating function $G(x,y;\xi)$.

Are there some know results that might be helpful anybody could point me to?